# Generating DIFFERENT executable from different files using ONE Makefile

Tags: c, makefile, executable

I have three files written in C:

```
a.c, b.c, d.c
```

I want to use ONE Makefile to generate independent executable files from them, like this:

```
a.x, b.x d.x.
```

They don't need each other to run. They are completely different programs.

I know, I can write a line to compile each one of them, like this:

```
gcc -Wall -Werror a.c -o a.x
gcc -Wall -Werror b.c -o b.x
gcc -Wall -Werror d.c -o d.x
```

But I am searching for an easier solution to do this independently from the number of files, due to the fact, that in the future I am going to have a lot of them.

I have an original that looks like this:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall - Werror -03
%.x:%.c
    ${CC} {CFLAGS} -o $@ $<
clean: 
    rm -f *.o
```

But I don't know, how to customize it, so that it read each one of my c-files and generate a x-file from each one of them.

Thanks

Comment: You could try reading the `make` documentation or any of the numerous guides to using it that can be found on the web.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried adding

all: a.x b.x c.x

in front of your makefile?

```
all: a.x b.x c.x

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall - Werror -03
%.x:%.c
    ${CC} {CFLAGS} -o $@ $<
clean: 
    rm -f *.o
```

Edit: To build all the .c files in the directory, try

```
all: $(*.c:.c=.x)
```

I'm quite rusty on Make so this might not quite be right ... You should read the Make documentation.

Edit 2: Indeed that wasn't right ... this is more likely to work:

```
SRCS = *.c

all: $(SRCS:.c=.x)
```

Or

```
SRCS = *.c
PGMS = $(SRCS:.c=.x)

all: $PGMS
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! 
Do you know about a solution, where I don't have to type down all the names for the executable files? (I have to compile 20 executables!) 
I want that Makefile just adopt the name of the c-file and use it for the respective x-file.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it is not quite right, but gets me in the right direction.
Both options compile "a.c" into "*.x" but leave b.c and d.c uncompiled.

Comment: I haven't checked, but you may want to use something like `SRCS=$(wildcard *.c)`, that will be expanded to all `.c` files in the current directory. See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html#File-Name-Functions for more information.